# Show that H = {(x , y) : 2x - 3y = 1} is NOT a subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G = $\mathbb{R}^2$= {(x , y): x and y $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$}. The group operation is addition of vectors. Show that H = {(x , y) : 2x - 3y = 1} is NOT a subgroup of G.

So far i have:

G = {0,1,2,3,...,n} , I have a H = {-3,-4,1,2} which are x and y values which make our statement true from here im not really sure what to do, although I am fairly sure i need to come up with a finite order for H and use MOD to show its not a subgroup just not sure how to do it from here.

Comment: $H$ does not contain $0$.

Comment: I didn't include 0 in H?

Comment: lhf's point is that the additive identity has to be in every subgroup.

Comment: I SEE... i think, so there in lies the answer then? Since, 0 cannot be in H and the additive identity must always contain 0. Therefore, H cannot be a subgroup of G?

Comment: A subgroup is itself a group.  Since the identity, $(0,0)$, is unique in $G$ it must the the identity in $H$.  If $H$ is a group it contains its identity.  Since $(0,0) \not \in H$, $H$ is not a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the problem is stated, you can just note that $0$ is not in $H$. However, if the problem were to say that $0$ is also included in $H$, then you could just take two non-zero elements $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ both in $H$ and then take the sum to get $(x,y)$ and then ask what is $2x - 3y$, can it be equal to $1$? $2x - 3y$ is a linear function so it is additive.